# Message sent to deallocated object '_UITextTiledLayer' object

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiscrollview

I have an `UIScrollView` with drawing on it's content view. I also have zoom functionality. I am adding `UIView` with `UITextViews` as its subview on zoom and removing `UIView` with `UITextViews` when user pinch out zoom. Sometimes it works fine but sometimes its crashing.

Also console continuous shows different combinations of these and more :

```
CALayerGetSuperlayer called on instance of UIScrollViewDelayedTouchesBeganGestureRecognizer
CALayerGetSuperlayer called on instance of __NSCFDictionary
CALayerGetSuperlayer called on instance of __NSArrayM
CALayerGetSuperlayer called on instance of __NSCFString
CALayerGetSuperlayer called on instance of __NSCFType
```

I have attached a screenshot of the instrument with zombies template. Which shows the summary of message sent to deallocated object.

[image]

Some of my code which will useful for solving this problem.
I am returning CATiledLayer to ensure zoomed content is sharp.

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self) {
        CATiledLayer *tiledLayer = (CATiledLayer *)[self layer];
        tiledLayer.levelsOfDetail = 4;
        tiledLayer.levelsOfDetailBias = 4;
    }
    return self;
}

+ layerClass
{
    return [CATiledLayer class];
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    CATiledLayer *tiledLayer = (CATiledLayer *)self.layer;
    tiledLayer.contents=nil;
    tiledLayer.delegate=nil;
    [tiledLayer removeFromSuperlayer];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be i'm wrong but, why do you instantiate a `CATiledLayer`in the `dealloc` method, this is physically wrong...
From what i know the reason of this error is either you are trying to dealloc an already deallocated object, or the object you are deallocating is empty

Comment: In dealloc, I am removing tiledLayer from superview because I have to stop tiledLayer's asynchronous drawing.

Comment: thanks your suggestion works for me. I removed all the CATiledLayer from dealloc method and only put "self.layer.contents = nil;".